# get categories from the specific product in the format of group

Tags: magento2

I have to retrieve the category collection in this form

1.For example A is Default category assigned to another category 
 DefaultCategoey /Women , Defaut Catgeory/Women/Clothes

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a product's category given the product ID? Or do you want to retrieve a product's category and the sub category of the product's category? Please be clear in your description.

Comment: retrrieve the product category and the subcategory

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step to get the product category ids from the product id:

The product category ids that the below code returns are the category ids that you specify when creating a product.

[image: Product Categories]

You need to instantiate `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList` class in your `__construct()` method to get category ids for a product.

```php
    /**
     * @var ProductCategoryList
     */
    public $productCategory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductCategoryList $productCategory
    ) {
        $this->productCategory = $productCategory;
    }

    /**
     * get all the category id
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCategoryIds(int $productId)
    {
        $categoryIds = $this->productCategory->getCategoryIds($productId);
        $category = [];
        if ($categoryIds) {
            $category = array_unique($categoryIds);
        }
        return $category;
    }
```

The `$category` will be an unique array of categories of the product.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , But I need in the Format i.e Gear/Bag Gear/collection

Comment: If we clcik the Equipment also then it shows in this format  Gear/Bag Gear/collection , Gear/Training/subcategory

Comment: need to display the category in form of group which is selected above